# How to change only the maximum value of a group which only have sum of certain number in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset

```
Item Count
A    60
A    20
A    21
B    35
B    33
B    32
C    40
C    40
C    10
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 60],
    ['A', 20],
    ['A', 21],
    ['B', 35],
    ['B', 33],
    ['B', 32],
    ['C', 40],
    ['C', 40],
    ['C', 10],
], 
    columns=['Item', 'Count'])
```

so here we can see Sum of Item column is: A: 101, B: 100, C:90
Now I want sum of all group of column "Item" to be 100 or less than 100 and reduce the extra number from the highest value of group.

The output should be like this:

```
Item Count
A    59
A    20
A    21
B    35
B    33
B    32
C    40
C    40
C    10
```

I tried.

```
idx = df.groupby("Item")["Count"].idxmax()
df.loc[idx, "Count"] -= ((df.groupby(['Item'])['Count'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())) - 100)
```

but all the groups highest value was subtracted by 100. I was unable to use IF condition only for group which has sum of more than 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code checks each row to see if the grouped sum is greater than 100, and if it is it looks for the maximum value in the group and reduces it by the difference between the sum and 100. All this is captured within the `assign` method.

```
(
    df.assign(
        counter=df.groupby("Item").Count.transform("sum"),
        maximum=df.groupby("Item").Count.transform("max"),
        Count=lambda x: np.where(
            x.counter.gt(100) & (x.Count.eq(x.maximum)),
            x.Count.sub(x.counter.sub(100)),
            x.Count,
        ),
    ).iloc[:, :2]
)

  Item  Count
0   A   59
1   A   20
2   A   21
3   B   35
4   B   33
5   B   32
6   C   40
7   C   40
8   C   10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with groupby:

```
>>> df.assign(
              Count=
                     df.groupby('Item',as_index=False)
                       .transform(lambda x:
                                  x.where(x!=x.max(), x-(x.sum()-100)) if x.sum()>100
                                                                      else x)
              )
  Item  Count
0    A   59.0
1    A   20.0
2    A   21.0
3    B   35.0
4    B   33.0
5    B   32.0
6    C   40.0
7    C   40.0
8    C   10.0
```

Comment: this method doesnot change the highest value... it changes the first value

Comment: Ah, missed the highest value part. I will delete the answer.